# rabbitmq createConnection throws error [Error: Connection ended: possibly due to an authentication failure.]

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Hi I trying to connect with rabbitmq using node.js
but getting error.
[Error: Connection ended: possibly due to an authentication failure.]

```
    var MessageQueue = AMQP.createConnection({'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' =>  '5672', 'login' => 'guest', 'password' => 'guest'});
MessageQueue.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('success);
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Can you log in to the management console with _guest/guest_?

Comment: @Datz has a good suggestion. Also, you should see something informative in your RabbitMQ logs - what is there?

Comment: @Datz Yes I can login and status is running there.

Comment: @LukeBakken 
I have checked logs and find this:
{handshake_error,tuning,0,{exit,{amqp_error,not_allowed,"negotiated channel_max = 0 is higher than the maximum allowed value (2047)",'connection.tune'}

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you have pointed out:

```
{handshake_error,tuning,0,{exit,{amqp_error,not_allowed,"negotiated channel_max = 0 is higher than the maximum allowed value (2047)",'connection.tune'}
```

This means that your client library is trying to use `0` as the value for `channel_max`, which means "infinite". RabbitMQ's limit out of the box is `2047` for safety reasons.

When reporting problems, you *must* tell people what software you are using, and the versions. In this case, I have no idea what javascript library you are using.

In the case of the [`amqp.node`](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node) library, you can specify a non-zero `channelMax` value.

Comment: Hi Luke,
I am using node version :  v0.10.25 and  {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.7.7"},

Comment: Please provide a link to the node.js / javascript library you are using to connect to RabbitMQ. This is whatever provides `AMQP.createConnection` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have fixed the issues. It is working fine now. Thank you guys for helping me out. 
I have changed channel_max = 0 to 20 and now it is working fine for me.